# Where is Magneto's island geographically located in Dark Phoenix?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-dark-phoenix

There's a scene where Jean goes to see Magneto who is living with mutants on a secluded island. We can see some labels/signs in exterior shots, and they're all in Hindi. That made me think it was somewhere around India.

A while later, Magneto says, rather confusingly, that the US government gave him that land.

Since this island could be a stand-in for [Genosha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genosha), can anyone tell me where it's supposed to be located in the film's universe?

Comment: I've kept plot details out of the question as much as possible. If there's anything that could be considered a spoiler, please tell me or feel free to edit.

Comment: In an [interview](https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/x-men-dark-phoenix-trailer-breakdown-director-simon-kinberg/) with Empire Online, Simon Kinberg said "What you’re seeing is the beginnings of Genosha".

Comment: I haven't seen Dark Phoenix but I believe the island actually *is* Genosha. That doesn't mean it's in the same place it is in the comic books, of course.

Comment: Found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/MCUTheories/comments/9jefri/magneto_is_in_india_during_dark_phoenix_the_words/) thread, containing also a relevant screenshot.

Comment: "***Q. Where is Genosha located? A. The Indian Ocean***" - From the *X-Men: Legends* video game